# c++ variadic templates and template template arguments: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I get **error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list...** when I compile the following code. The compiler is gcc version 8.2.0.

```
template<typename>
struct t1 {};

template<typename ...>
struct t2 {};

template<typename, typename ...>
struct t3 {};

template<template<typename> class>
struct tt1 {};

template<template<typename ...> class>
struct tt2{};

template<template<typename, typename ...> class>
struct tt3{};


tt1<t2> _1; // error
tt1<t3> _2; // error
tt2<t1> _3;
tt2<t3> _4;
tt3<t1> _5;
tt3<t2> _6; // error
```

**Question**: Why **_3**, **_4**, **_5** are allowed and **_1**, **_2**, **_6** are wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These errors are errors in pre C++17. Before C++17, template template argument / parameter shall match exactly.

But since addition of [P0522R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0522r0.html) to the standard, the rule are less strict, and this code compiles.

As of today, I thing only GCC implements it and you need to specify the standard:`gcc -std=c++17` [see here](https://godbolt.org/z/lPnehw).